# Removing lines using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

[image]

How do I make this map remove those lines and just view the map as one?

What I mean is I wanted to remove those lines so that the outcome will just be a plain map without those lines.

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit the `style` of the layer, and set the outline (border) color to be the same as the fill color

Answer (score 4):

Change the Style of the layer by right-clicking it, then choose `Properties`-> `Style`.
Then click `Simple fill`. Last step is to choose `Outline style`-> `No pen`.
Now the outlines will be removed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it will however leave a noticeable tiny empty space between the polygons

Comment: @JGH I always just shrugged that hairline gap off as a display artifact and never noticed it in print. Have you seen otherwise?

Comment: @GabrielC. Yes. I guess it depends on the scale/polygon size. See this [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feazd.png) and part of its [export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMCUs.png). PDF is even worst. That's why I always set the outline line to be of the same color, so it is never noticeable :)